# UIBezierPath draws differently in storyboard and simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, ibdesignable

I'm creating a custom `IBDesignable` control and I want to draw a set of **squares** in there. I have a `draw(_ rect:)` method which does the following:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // ... skipped ...
        
        for i in 0 ..< 7 {
            for j in 0 ... 6 {

                let x = Double(i) * (cellSize + space)
                let y = Double(j) * (cellSize + space)
                
                let rectangle = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: cellSize, height: cellSize)
                let face = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rectangle, cornerRadius: CGFloat(0))

                face.fill()
            }
        }
    }
```

This works just fine when I add the component into interface builder and I can see the squares. But when I run it in the simulator it draws rectangles but **not squares**:

[image]

This seems quite weird as `width` is equal to `height`. It works same way even if I draw with lines:

```
let face = UIBezierPath()
face.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
face.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + cellSize, y: y))
face.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + cellSize, y: y + cellSize))
face.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y + cellSize))
face.close()
```

or if I use regular not round corner rectangle:

```
let face = UIBezierPath(rect: rectangle)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is timing. The view is being drawn using squares, but then the interface is laid out and the view height is made a little smaller or its width is made a little larger. The drawing is cached — you have not set the view to be [redrawn](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode/redraw) when its bounds change — so the drawing is now slightly distorted, as if a scale transform had been applied to it with a different horizontal value from the vertical value. Hence the squares are no longer square.

Comment: Seems like that. Fixed by forcing redraw when bounds are changed.

Comment: You don't need to "force" it. It is a built in setting. But you didn't turn it on. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode/redraw

Comment: Well, this works. But what if I want to make this "transparent" for everyone else? So that when they add view to IB they don't need to change the setting.